# is there a straight forward way to AND to validate multiple conditions in Joi

Tags: node.js, joi

What i am look for is to validate a field based on two or more conditions connected with AND.

my schema looks like

```
mySchema = joi.object({
  "field": condition1 && condition2
})
```

so the schema should be validated, if two conditions are true

Comment: could you please share what the conditions are?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to make the field required and have at least 3 characters (Joi version 17.4.0).

```
const Joi = require('joi');
    
function validateField(fieldList){
    
        const schema = Joi.object(
            {
                field: Joi.string()
                .min(3)
                .required()
            }
        )
    
        return schema.validate(fieldList);
    
    };
```